# How to use the Wolfram Language Symbol entity type to list all the entity types?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, symbols, entity

I would like to map EntityValue[#,"SampleEntities"] over all the domains of entities, but before I spend 20 to 30 minutes typing every single entity, I would like to be aware of any way to list all the entity types with Wolfram Language Symbol entity's framework.
I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: `EntityValue[]`?

Comment: Please post a working example about your question.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about this feature!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of all entity types using `EntityValue[]`:

```
Row[EntityValue[], "▪"]
```

[image]